# UIPicker cannot be a delegate?

Tags: ios, uidatepicker

I created an IBOutlet for a UIPicker and named it 'RequestedDate.'  I then went on the type

> _RequestedDate.delegate = self;

but I keep getting the error:

> property 'delegate' not found on object type 'UIDatePicker'

I am relatively new with Xcode and am just starting to work with code. Is there something I am doing wrong or cannot I not have a delegate for a UIPicker?

Thanks~

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think UIDatePicker has a delegate property. https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIDatePicker_Class/Reference/UIDatePicker.html

What are you trying to do exactly?

Comment: I am trying to use the data from the picker to bring to parse.com backend. I have been able to successfully do this with the text fields but I can't seem to figure out how to do it with a UIPICKER.

Comment: You can just use `_RequestedDate.date` to get the current date set on the picker (like if the user clicks a button and you want the date that the picker is currently set to). But if you need to know when the picker actually was changed use Matthias' answer.

Answer (score 1):

UIDatePicker uses the target-action pattern instead of the delegate pattern.
You either add a IBAction for the 'value changed' event in Interface Builder or you do it in code like this:

```
UIDatePicker *datePicker = [[UIDatePicker alloc] init];
[datePicker addTarget:self action:@selector(datePickerDidChange:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
// ...
```

Then you implement the action method, and can retrieve the new date.

```
- (void)datePickerDidChange:(UIDatePicker *)picker {
    NSDate *newDate = picker.date;
    NSLog(@"Picker changed date to %@", newDate);
}
```

UIPickerView and UIDatePicker only look similar, they are completely separate classes. UIPickerView is a subclass of UIView and UIDatePicker is a subclass of UIControl, they are not related.